# Personal build with dependencies

Tags: teamcity

I've started using TeamCity personal builds, via the new Git remote run feature in TeamCity 6.5. Doing a single build works fine; I have a project that compiles from source, and I gave it a  Branch Remote Run trigger.

However, it looks like TeamCity only triggers the one project that has the Branch Remote Run trigger applied. I have several unit test projects, set up in a chain with Finish Build triggers, and none of these get run. Furthermore, if I try to start a custom build of one of these unit test projects, I can't use the artifacts from my personal build: I can only pick artifacts from one of the 'official' builds.

Can I get TeamCity personal builds to work with build chains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the setup that you have (snapshot dependencies and finish build triggers), you can achieve build chaining by submitted your personal changes to the builds you are looking to trigger. For example, if you have projects A and B where B depends on A - run the remote build against project B and A will be triggered first and B will be added to the queue. Both of these builds will have your personal changes.

If you are using the TeamCity Visual Studio plugin you can select which builds you want to send your changes to and you just need to tick the box for B instead of A.

The finished build trigger won't be fired, but the build chaining means that A must be built first.

More info - http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Build+Chain

(You have tagged TeamCity 6.5, but 7 has now been released so I have included the documentation for the newer version)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you should setup your chain not with Finish Build trigger, but with "Snapshot dependencies" feature of TeamCity. And, setup artifacts dependency basing on the snapshots.

Please read about snapshot dependencies in TeamCity [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Dependent+Build#DependentBuild-SnapshotDependency).

Comment: Thanks - I have snapshot dependencies set up already, and they work fine for non-personal builds. If I remove the Finish Build trigger then not only do the personal builds not work, but also the non-personal builds stop triggering.